# How can we write the below characteristic function?

Tags: probability, random-variable, characteristic-function

Let us assume that $X$ is a random variable and $a$ is a constant. Now suppose $Y=a+bX$, what would the characteristic function of $Y$ would be? Is it?
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}_X\left[\exp(iuY)\right]&=&\mathbb{E}_X\left[\exp(iu\{a+bX\})\right]\\
&=&\mathbb{E}_X\left[\exp(iua)\exp(iubX)\right]
\end{eqnarray}
How can this be decomposed further? What is the intuition behind the characteristic function of a constant $a$? Would it be wrong to further decompose the above as 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_X\left[\exp(iuY)\right]\overset{?}{=}\exp(iua)\mathbb{E}_X\left[\exp(iubX)\right]
\end{equation}
given that $a$ is a constant? Not even sure that is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that [expectation is a linear functional?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22linearity+of+expectation%22)  If not, that's the very first thing to study next.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure I follow. Yes if we have $\mathbb{E}(X+Y)$ that can be expressed as $\mathbb{E}(X)+\mathbb{E}{(Y)}$, but if we have $\mathbb{E}(\exp(X+Y))$ that is no longer the case, as it can only be decomposed to $\mathbb{E}(\exp(X)\exp(Y))$. Could you please elaborate further? Perhaps I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: *Linear* means that for any numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ and any random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n,$ $$\mathbb{E}(a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_nX_n)=a_1\mathbb{E}(X_1)+a_2\mathbb{E}(X_2)+\cdots+a_n\mathbb{E}(X_n).$$ Apply this to the case $n=1$ and $a_1=\exp(iua)$ (which is a number).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for elaboration. I am aware of the above and hence my final derivation. In that case that implies that my last decomposition correct. Right? I was conflicted with this result, as I wasn't sure about the intuition of $\exp(iua)$ without an expectation operator.

Comment: It's just a number.

Comment: @whuber thank you very much.

Comment: It occurs to me the concern might be that $\exp(iua)$ is generally a Complex number.  One way to see that the linearity of expectation holds for complex numbers such as $w=a+bi$ and complex-valued random variables $Z=X+iY$ is to note that $$wZ=(a+bi)(X+iY)=aX - bY + (bX + aY)i,$$ so once you accept that expectation must be linear with respect to multiplication by the Complex unit $i,$ set $a_1=a,$ $a_2=-b,$ $a_3=bi,$ and $a_4=ai$ corresponding to the random variables $X,Y,X,Y$ respectively.